# ALM API Call to fetch the fields from Test Lab

Tags: rest, alm, hp-quality-center, microfocus

I am trying to migrate from ALM OTA architecture towards API calls, I have a piece of code in OTA
that is added below, trying to replicate similar with API calls. In the TestLab module. Any help
will be appreciated.

```
*--OTA code*
Set objTreeManager=QcCon.TestSetTreeManager
Set objSubjectNode=objTreeManager.NodeByPath("Root\\MyFolder\\MyTestLab")
\*//objSubjectNode will have the object of MyTestLab\*
Set objTestSetFactory=objSubjectNode.TestSetFactory
*//objTestSetFactory will have filter fields and history*
Set objFilter=objTestSetFactory .Filter
*//objFilter will have fields of DataType CYCLE*
Set oDFileds=get_field_lables("CYCLE") //Function call
*//oDFileds will have fields like 'Attachment','Baseline',Open Date, Has Linkage etc....*
```

Tried something like this

`http://{{SERVERNAME}}/qcbin/rest/domains/{{DOMAIN}}/projects/{{PROJECT}}/test-parameters`

Couldn't get the relevant answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate towards QC REST API, that is possible, but you need to check:

1. Which QC version are you using. The QC-10 is different from QC-12 or QC-15 or latest 17.
2. Once you know the version, I hardly encourage you to have a look at the REST API material from Micro Focus.
3. First steps will be to login and to create a session where to send all your requests.
4. Modify Test Lab / Test Plan / Defects / Test Instances....everything will be possible towards REST API.

It is possible then to collect an XML with all parameter from a Test Plan...
As said with the information above, that is maximum I can suggest.
Hope that will help a bit. I have used QC for a decade and always automated over REST API...much simpler and quick accessing/reporting data. You can use Python or Java for REST scripts. Have a great one!